# My custom theme does not load the translations

Tags: theme-development, translation

I made a custom theme named `testTheme` having these files:

[image: The files of my theme]

And I wanted to put some translation on it therefore I created the required .po and .mo files for greek language via poedit as seen in the following image:

[image: Theme files]

But I cannot make it load the custom translations I created via poedit. Do you have any idea how I will load them?

## Edit 1

The `functions.php` as asked:

```
<?php


if(!function_exists('loadThemerequirements')):

function loadThemerequirements()
{
    load_theme_textdomain( 'testTheme', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );
}

endif;

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'loadThemerequirements' );
```

### Update1

The translations files were moved and renamed like that:

[image: New translation files]

Still Same result.

## Edit 2:

This is not a child theme but a from-scratch made one.

## Edit 3:

I tried renaming the .po and .mo files as `el_GR.po` and `el_GR.mo` still same result. I also tried to rename them in to `testTheme/el_GR.po` and `testTheme/el_GR.mo` without any success.

### Update 2

The theme is in this git repository: https://github.com/pc-magas/testTheme

### Edit 1

I changed my 404 page (that has some text to be translated into greek) like that:

```
<?php
get_header();
?>
<div class="fullpage_center">
    <div>
        <h1>404</h1>
        <p><?php _e('The requested page does not exist.','testTheme');?></p>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
    wp_reset_query(); //resetting the page query
    get_footer();
?>
```

A sample of my page and the translated text is:

[image: 404 page with text that needs to be translated]

As you can see still no result.

Comment: show us the code you use in `functions.php` to load the translations

Comment: 1. edit your translate file name from `testTheme-el` to `testTheme-el_GR` 2. set your textdomain in `_e` or `__` functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Change your translate file name to `el_GR.po` and `el_GR.mo`:

   ```
   el_GR.po in: testTheme\languages\el.po
   el_GR.mo in: testTheme\languages\el.mo
   ```
2. In 404.php file for print text you should write code like this (add textdomain):

   ```
   <?php _e('The requested page does not exist.', 'testTheme'); ?>
   ```

Second parameter is textdomain.

Comment: Do I need to reinstall my theme? I develop it straight through a wordpress installation without reinstalling or re-enabling.

Comment: No, just add textdomain to your strings

Comment: Also do I need to rename my theme's folder into `testTheme-master` currently is into folder `testTheme`

Comment: excuse me. template folder name is mistake! folder name not need rename.

Comment: But still I cannot get the translated text from the 404 page I get the English one.

Comment: What is your wordpress language?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56064/discussion-between-mahdiy-and-dimitrios-desyllas).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a child theme, in your function.php you have to change `get_template_directory()` by `get_stylesheet_directory()`

Comment: I do not have a child theme. It is a pure-made theme from scratch.

Comment: Do you see any parent theme in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJ2x9.png)?

Comment: Also I tried it and still no result.